# Data-attribute list to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, custom-data-attribute

I have:

```
<img id="img" data-list="['image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg']" src="image1.jpg">
```

How can i get images listed in data-list to array varible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the data from the `img`, format it as a JSON, and use JSON#parse to convert it to an array:

```js
var img = document.querySelector('#img');
var array = JSON.parse(img.dataset.list.replace(/'/g, '"'));

console.log(array);
```

```html
<img id="img" data-list="['image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg']" src="image1.jpg">
```